# Spring Webflux Proper Way To Find and Save

Tags: java, spring-webflux, reactive-streams

I created the below method to find an Analysis object, update the results field on it and then lastly save the result in the database but not wait for a return.

```
public void updateAnalysisWithResults(String uuidString, String results) {
        findByUUID(uuidString).subscribe(analysis -> {
            analysis.setResults(results);
            computeSCARepository.save(analysis).subscribe();
        });
    }
```

This feels poorly written to subscribe within a subscribe.
Is this a bad practice?
Is there a better way to write this?

UPDATE:
entry point

```
@PatchMapping("compute/{uuid}/results")
    public Mono<Void> patchAnalysisWithResults(@PathVariable String uuid, @RequestBody String results) {
        return computeSCAService.updateAnalysisWithResults(uuid,results);
    }
```

```
    public Mono<Void> updateAnalysisWithResults(String uuidString, String results) {
//        findByUUID(uuidString).subscribe(analysis -> {
//            analysis.setResults(results);
//            computeSCARepository.save(analysis).subscribe();
//        });
        return findByUUID(uuidString)
                .doOnNext(analysis -> analysis.setResults(results))
                .doOnNext(computeSCARepository::save)
                .then();
    }
```

Comment: you might not even subscribe at all, who calls this function?

Comment: A PATCH endpoint on the controller @Toerktumlare without subscribe it wasn't saving to database for some reason

Comment: This is most likely necause you are `breaking the reactive chain` if you post a full code example i might be able to help you. Are you returning void? Because a common way is to return `Mono<Void>` and try to avoid pure void functions

Comment: @Toerktumlare sure! I shared the rest of my code and tried updating it to use mono<void>. Doesn't seem to work like this

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Why it is not working is because you have misunderstood what `doOnNext` does.

Lets start from the beginning.

A `Flux` or `Mono` are producers, they produce items. Your application produces things to the calling client, hence it should always return either a `Mono` or a `Flux`. If you don't want to return anything you should return a `Mono<Void>`.

When the client `subscribes` to your application what reactor will do is call all operators in the opposite direction until it finds a `producer`. This is what is called the `assembly phase`. If all your operators don't chain together you are what i call `breaking the reactive chain`.

When you break the chain, the things broken from the chain wont be executed.

If we look at your example but in a more exploded version:

```
@Test
void brokenChainTest() {
    updateAnalysisWithResults("12345", "Foo").subscribe();
}

public Mono<Void> updateAnalysisWithResults(String uuidString, String results) {
    return findByUUID(uuidString)
            .doOnNext(analysis -> analysis.setValue(results))
            .doOnNext(this::save)
            .then();
}

private Mono<Data> save(Data data) {
    return Mono.fromCallable(() -> {
        System.out.println("Will not print");
        return data;
    });
}

private Mono<Data> findByUUID(String uuidString) {
    return Mono.just(new Data());
}

private static class Data {
    private String value;

    public void setValue(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

in the above example `save` is a `callable` function that will return a `producer`. But if we run the above function you will notice that the `print` will never be executed.

This has to do with the usage of `doOnNext`. If we read the docs for it it says:

> Add behavior triggered when the Mono emits a data successfully.
> The Consumer is executed first, then the onNext signal is propagated downstream.

`doOnNext` takes a [`Consumer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Consumer.html?is-external=true) that returns void. And if we look at `doOnNext` we see that the function description looks as follows:

```
public final Mono<T> doOnNext(Consumer<? super T> onNext)`
```

THis means that it takes in a consumer that is a `T` or extends a `T` and it returns a `Mono<T>`. So to keep a long explanation short, you can see that it consumes something but also returns the same something.

What this means is that this usually used for what is called `side effects` basically for something that is done *on the side* that does not hinder the current flow. One of those things could for instance logging. Logging is one of those things that would consume for instance a string and log it, while we want to keep the string flowing down our program. Or maybe we we want to increment a number on the side. Or modify some state somewhere. You can read all about side effects [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Side_effect_(computer_science)).

you can of think of it visually this way:

```
     _____ side effect (for instance logging)
    /
___/______ main reactive flow
```

That's why your first `doOnNext` setter works, because you are *modifying a state on the side*, you are setting the value on your class hence modifying the state of your class to have a value.

The second statement on the other hand, the save, does not get executed. You see that function is actually returning something we need to take care of.

This is what it looks like:

```
      save
     _____ 
    /     \   < Broken return
___/             ____ no main reactive flow
```

all we have to do is actually change one single line:

```
// From
.doOnNext(this::save)

// To
.flatMap(this::save)
```

`flatMap` takes whatever is in the `Mono`, and then we can use that to execute something and then return a "new" something.

So our flow (with flatMap) now looks like this:

```
   setValue()    save()
    ______       _____ 
   /            /     \   
__/____________/       \______ return to client
```

So with the use of `flatMap` we are now saving and returning whatever was returned from that function triggering the rest of the chain.

If you then choose to ignore whatever is returned from the `flatMap` its completely correct to do as you have done to call `then` which will

> Return a Mono which only replays complete and error signals from this

The general rule is, in a fully reactive application, **you should never block**.

And you generally don't `subscribe` unless your application is the final `consumer`. Which means if your application started the request, then you are the `consumer`of something else so you `subscribe`. If a webpage starts off the request, then they are the final `consumer` and they are subscribing.

If you are subscribing in your application that is producing data its like you are running a bakery and eating your baked breads at the same time.

don't do that, its bad for business :D

Comment: This was an extremely through and easy to understand explanation! Thank you SO much. I was kind of struggling to understand some of the concepts but I feel like I have a good understanding finally!

Answer (score 0):

Subscribe inside a subscribe is not a good practise. You can use `flatMap` operator to solve this problem.

```
public void updateAnalysisWithResults(String uuidString, String results) {
        findByUUID(uuidString).flatMap(analysis -> {
            analysis.setResults(results);
            return computeSCARepository.save(analysis);
        }).subscribe();
    }
```