# Transfer file and store file id (elasticsearch) via webflux (spring-boot)

Tags: java, spring-boot, elasticsearch, spring-webflux

I'm trying to transfer files to a third party service via webflux and store the file ids in a elasticsearch. Files are transferred and saved, but the id is not attached to the entity.

controller:

```java
@PostMapping(value = "upload", consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public Flux<String> store(@RequestParam(required = false) String orderId, @RequestPart("file") Flux<FilePart> files){
        return imageService.store(orderId, files);
    }
```

service:

```java
    public Flux<String> store(String orderId, Flux<FilePart> files) {
        return marketService.findById(orderId)
                .filter(Objects::nonNull)
                .flatMapMany(order -> {
                    return files.ofType(FilePart.class).flatMap(file -> save(orderId, file));
                });
    }

    private Mono<String> save(String orderId, FilePart file) {
        return file.content()
                .flatMap(dataBuffer -> {
                    byte[] bytes = new byte[dataBuffer.readableByteCount()];
                    dataBuffer.read(bytes);
                    String image = storeApi.upload(bytes, file.filename());
                    DataBufferUtils.release(dataBuffer);
                    return Mono.just(image);
                })
                .doOnNext(image -> marketService.addImages(orderId, image))
                .last();
    }
```

marketService.addImages:

```java
    public Mono<Order> addImages(String id, String image){
        log.info("addImages: id={}, image={}", id, image);
        return orderRepository
                .findById(id)
                .doOnNext(order -> {
                    if(order.getProduct().getImages() == null){
                        order.getProduct().setImages(new ArrayList<>());
                    }
                    order.getProduct().getImages().add(image);
                })
                .flatMap(this::create);
    }
```

The code in the **doOnNext** and **flatMap** block in method (**addImages**) does not work. In doing so, calling the method (**addImages**) from the controller works fine. Tell me please what i'm missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I have found a solution. I changed the operation from doOnNext to flatMap as per this solution: [Spring Webflux Proper Way To Find and Save](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71699924/spring-webflux-proper-way-to-find-and-save)

```java
public Mono<OrderPostgres> store(String orderId, Flux<FilePart> files) {
        return marketService.findById(orderId)
                .filter(Objects::nonNull)
                .flatMapMany(order -> {
                    return files.ofType(FilePart.class)
                            .flatMap(file -> save(orderId, file))
                            .collectList();
                })
                .flatMap(image -> marketService.addImages(orderId, image))
                .then(Mono.empty());
    }

    private Flux<String> save(String orderId, FilePart file) {
        return file.content()
                .log()
                .flatMap(dataBuffer -> {
                    byte[] bytes = new byte[dataBuffer.readableByteCount()];
                    dataBuffer.read(bytes);
                    String image = storeApi.upload(bytes, file.filename());
                    DataBufferUtils.release(dataBuffer);
                    return Flux.just(image);
                }).switchIfEmpty(Flux.empty());
    }

public Mono<OrderPostgres> addImages(String id, List<String> images){
        log.info("### addImage: id={}, images={}", id, images);

        Mono<OrderPostgres> byId = orderRepository.findById(id);
        return byId
                .flatMap(order -> {
                    if (order.getImages() == null) {
                        order.setImages(new ArrayList<>());
                    }
                    order.getImages().addAll(images);
                    return orderRepository.save(order);
                }).then(Mono.empty());
    }
```